# What is the simplest command line instruction in Ubuntu to export a directory file list to a text file?

Tags: command-line, bash

There is a folder consist of some different file types which most of them are font files. I use this simple command to export file names of *Fonts* folder to *Output* text file:

```
~/Fonts$ ls > ../Output
```

But I want suchlike command to export the name of all files with additional properties (Name, Style, Type, Size, Version, Copyright, Description and each attribute which displayed in font viewer) in front of file name  with a proper column space like below:

```
File Name            Name             Style         Type                 Size ,...
FreeSerif.ttf        FreeSerif        Medium        TrueType font        1.5 MB
FreeMono.ttf         FreeMono         Medium        TrueType font        343.3 kB
```

And what about *Fonts* directory with some subdirectory? How to show them like above plus a tree view?

**Note:** The Output is not important to be like above. I expect just a simple command which export file properties alongside file name.

Comment: I like this idea. Maybe a script? Sadly I know ****zero**** about fonts.

Comment: You've to write a script to extract all to style and type information out of a file name. I think you could use `awk`: `ls -lah | awk '{print $5 $9}'`. This prints the 5th column (size) and the 9th column (file name). Modify it to fit your needs.

Comment: Please do not double post your question ask a moderator to move your question to Unix&Linux if you fell it belongs there and suppress your second question.

Comment: This was crossposted to Unix & Linux at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/107108/10762.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

> [cjm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/2421/cjm) answer on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/):

*I think you're looking for otfinfo. There doesn't seem to be an option to get at the Subfamily directly, but you could do:*

```
otfinfo --info *.ttf | grep Subfamily
```

*Note that a number of the fonts I looked at use "Oblique" instead of "Italic".*

Link to the [original question & answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26053/is-there-a-unix-command-line-tool-that-can-analyze-font-files).

Comment: **otfinfo** not installed on my system!

Comment: @user1729 ...then install it? This information isn't going to come from nowhere, you need specialised tools for specialised solutions.